# Why does an overlap of atomic orbitals in a solid cause a continuous emission spectrum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, electrons, spectroscopy, orbitals

A given explanation for a light bulb's continuous spectrum of emitted light was that energy levels in solids overlap, therefore all energy changes can occur.

How can these changes occur? If an electron had enough energy to move into this 'overlap' space, how would it give out energy subsequently?

Can a spectrum ever be truly 'continuous'? Since the energy changes are just changes in discrete levels, tending towards a continuous distribution?

Comment: @JohnRennie I don't understand how this answers the question. How  exactly do energy levels in a solid overlap, and how come any energy change is possible if there are still determined shells?

Comment: @JonCuster I don't understand how this answers the question. How  exactly do energy levels in a solid overlap, and how come any energy change is possible if there are still determined shells?